# insert variable value take new line in insert mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

when i trying to insert variable value in databases it take as new line.

here is my mysql query:

```
$query4 = "insert into $table (create_date, COMMAND, File_name, parent_id, ack, status, response, response_time, cloud_file_size, download_file_size) values('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','wget' , 'abhi.tar.gz','','1', 'success', ' ".$str." ', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".$tar_size."', '".$size."')";
                    mysql_query($query4);
```

i think my variable take \n but i also use `$str=str_replace("\r\n","",$str);`

below insert query in mysql log:

```
insert into service_logs_2014_02 (create_date, COMMAND, File_name, parent_id, ack, status, response, response_time, cloud_file_size, download_file_size) values('2014-02-06 19:08:19','wget' , '123.tar.gz','','1', 'success', '

2014-02-0619:08:19(7.63MB/s)-`/var/www/html/123/SRC/123.tar.gz'saved[1074190/1074190]

', '2014-02-06 19:08:19', '1.1M        ', '1.1M        ')
```

please provide solution.

Comment: Solution for WHICH question?

Comment: because of break line in insert query it's not update the table.

Comment: If you want to update your line, you must do a 'UPDATE' not an 'INSERT'. Or I didn't understand your problem :o

Comment: @Nanis ..plz see my mysql query log.

Comment: Edit : OK understood sorry, didn't you have any hidden characters on your code ?

Comment: @codemania: open the log file in any text editor with word wrap disabled. you won't find the said new line. And your problem is not with new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution.

problem with `grave accent` and `Apostrophe`(') symbol witch coming on my value

see below:

```
2014-02-0619:08:19(7.63MB/s)-`/var/www/html/123/SRC/123.tar.gz'saved[1074190/1074190]
```

i removed both symbol and problem solved.

thanks for your support guys.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what your question is, but if I understand you correctly, you want to remove the newlines from the String you're trying to put into the query?

If so:

**Assuming the newlines will only occur at the start and end of the String:**

You'll want to use the `trim()` function. The trim function will remove any leading or trailing newlines and space characters. (which, looking at your query, you may want to use on other fields as well)

**If newlines can occur within the String:**

Simple solution would be using the `str_replace()` function to remove all newlines, followed by, again, the `trim()` function to remove any leadng/trailing spaces, like this:

```php
$str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('', ''), $str);
$str = trim($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because the value you insert have problem

```
2014-02-0619:08:19(7.63MB/s)-`/var/www/html/123/SRC/123.tar.gz'saved[1074190/1074190]
```

you have a ' before the "123.tar.gz" when insert the value. try use mysql_real_escape_string in your query

Example:

```
insert into service_logs_2014_02 (create_date, COMMAND, File_name, parent_id, ack, status, response, response_time, cloud_file_size, download_file_size) values('2014-02-06 19:08:19','wget' , '123.tar.gz','','1', 'success', mysql_real_escape_string('

2014-02-0619:08:19(7.63MB/s)-`/var/www/html/123/SRC/123.tar.gz'saved[1074190/1074190]

'), '2014-02-06 19:08:19', '1.1M        ', '1.1M        ')
```